# Parsing xml data with Jsoup in android studio

Tags: xml, kotlin, parsing, jsoup

I have the following code that doesn't seem to be working:

```
private fun xmlParse_Jsoup() {
    thread {
        val doc = Jsoup.parse("http://xmlweather.vedur.is/?op_w=xml&type=forec&lang=is&view=xml&ids=1;422")

        val listItems: Elements = doc.select("ul.list > li")
        for (item in listItems) System.out.println(item.text())

        val strings = doc.getElementsByTag("forecast")
    }
}
```

For now I'm just trying to read the file, but in the end the output is going to be all the tags under , the ftime, F, D, T and W tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select all `forecast` elements:

```
val listItems: Elements = doc.select("forecast")
```

Next, loop through your list and print the desired children:

```
for (item in listItems) {
    System.out.println(item.select("ftime"));
    System.out.println(item.select("f"));
    System.out.println(item.select("d"));
    System.out.println(item.select("t"));
    System.out.println(item.select("w"));
}
```

If you only want to print the text contained inside the child nodes, replace the above statements:

```
System.out.println(item.select(/* ... */));
```

with:

```
System.out.println(item.select(/* ... */).text());
```